# php mysql insert into with multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this:

```
$h = 'my forum name'; //stackoverflow reference

"INSERT INTO $h (`id`, `topic`, `dated`, `author`, `subforumname`) 
VALUES('NULL', '$d', '$e', '$f', '$g')"
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that it won't insert rows if $h is multiple words like "my forum name." It seems to be just fine if it's "myforum."

What do I need to put around the $h to make this work?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 trying this now

Comment: @AbraCadaver I believe I tried that and `` and it wouldn't insert any rows at all but I'll try again if @arif's doesn't work

Comment: Can you show in your example where you've put the `$h`?

Comment: Oh OP is using `$h` as the table name

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, didn't work

Comment: @StuartLC I SWEAR I tried this and it didn't work before. Seems to be working now. Maybe I had a typo? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table name contains spaces, you need to use backticks, so you would change your first line to this:

```
$h = "`my forum name`";
```

[MySQL Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

- Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:

  - ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
  - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
- ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters (U+10000 and higher) are not permitted in quoted or unquoted identifiers.
- Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.
- Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.

Comment: table names can contain spaces?

Comment: Yes, I would never do that, but apparently it's possible.

Comment: So they can. I wouldn't do it either.

Comment: I need them to be able to have spaces because the table names are dynamically created by users.

Comment: You could let them dynamically create them and replace the spaces by "_".

Comment: That would work but underscore is also a character they're allowed to use.